# What do i need for Ionic 2 - Anjular 2 or Typescript

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am a front end developer and i need to develop hybrid mobile applications using Ionic 2 Framework.

I tried to understand what i am going to need between Typescript and AnjularJS.

Do i need one of these or both?

Comment: Ionic 2 uses Angular 2 not AngularJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ionic2 has been developed on top of Angular and Typescript.So you have to learn both and also Ionic2 :).But if you know Javascript then Typescript is nothing.You can learn advanced stuff when you're developing your own apps (me myself doing it in that way right now :)).So you just need to get the basic knowledge only.Ionic2 is also very easy to learn.No need to tell about Angular.It's super easy to learn when compared to the AngularJs 1.X.

So why you're waiting? Let's start.Good Luck!

**Ionic2 :** [Beginners Guide Ionic2](https://www.joshmorony.com/beginners-guide-to-getting-started-with-ionic-2/)

**Typescript :** [Learn TypeScript in 30 Minutes (see I told you no :))](http://tutorialzine.com/2016/07/learn-typescript-in-30-minutes/)

**Angular :** [Guide for Beginners](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/06/ng2-getting-started-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have done any research in typescript, it basically is a superset of javascript. It means it contains everything javascript contains.The Ionic CLI supports generating both TypeScript and ES6 projects. Fortunately, the CLI handles all of the setup required to run both types of projects so there’s no heavy lifting required on the users end here.Types are pretty much the whole point of using TypeScript over ES6. The syntax differences aren’t huge and you should pretty easily be able to convert from one to the other.

Comment: Right, in fact, it is not really converting at all. If you program in a declarative fashion, you really only need to place type annotations on function arguments (but not on callback arguments), every other type will be inferred for you. By declarative fashion I mean everything has an initializer and is preferably declared `const`. That is good JavaScript and it leads to good TypeScript.